# .load() page doesn't run jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using .load() functions to add content to my page, but I can't get any jquery scripts to work on the loaded content.

Here's an example of the loaded page and script:

```
<div class="content">

    <div class="sections">
        <div id="holder">
            <div class="resumelink" id="educ">
                Education
            </div>
            <div class="resumelink" id="work">
                Work
            </div>
            <div class="resumelink" id="skills">
                Skills
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="resumecontent">
        blah blah blah
    </div>

    <script src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script> 
    <script>
            $('#educ').click(function () {
                // any script here
            });

            $('#work').click(function () {
                // any script here
            });

            $('#skills').click(function () {
                // any script here
            });
    </script>
</div>
```

There's some other posts that seems to have the same problem, but none of them seem to be helping me.  No scripts seem to be working no matter what I try - not when on the initial page that loaded the content - can't even get a console.log script to work.

The **SOLUTION**, provided by @Archer - is simply to add a jquery() tag and add to the original page instead of the loaded page.  An example:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).on("click", "#educ", function() {
        // any function here
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: did you check your console for any errors?

Comment: `I'm using .load() functions to add content..`  Why don't you show that code?

Comment: Are you saying the click event handlers are not executed  when you click on the divs? They should. You have to provide a better explanation if you want useful help.

Comment: AFAIK, `load()` will not execute scripts in the loaded content.

Comment: the .load() code functions fine - no issues with that.  @FelixKling yes that is what I'm saying.  I think they should too!

Comment: @Archer where do the scripts need to be then?  They don't run even when in the original page

Comment: You should put the script that assigns the click event handlers into the callback function of the `load()` method, or use event delegation.  Can you post the code where you actually load this extra content?

Comment: I've put a general answer to your problem below.  Have a try and let us know how you get on.

Comment: Assuming you are able to load this file, right? I mean, is the path correct? `<script src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>`

Comment: @Archer -- added the .load().  Hoping to avoid relying on callbacks, if only to keep things simple for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all the script references from the html that you load - they will not be executed when using `.load()`...

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="sections">
        <div id="holder">
            <div class="resumelink" id="educ">
                Education
            </div>
            <div class="resumelink" id="work">
                Work
            </div>
            <div class="resumelink" id="skills">
                Skills
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="resumecontent">
        blah blah blah
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, in your original page (or preferably an included script file), add the following...

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".content").on("click", "#educ", function() {
        // any script here
    });

    $(".content").on("click", "#work", function() {
        // any script here
    });

    $(".content").on("click", "#skills", function() {
        // any script here
    });
});
```

Comment: my man!  works perfect.  So the lesson is here all has to do with the way the script was called...  What does the jQuery() tag do that wasn't being accomplished before?

Comment: That's a document ready handler, it's not changing anything about what you were doing, other than waiting for the document to finish loading before running the script.  The main thing here is the fact that the click event handlers are attached to `.content`, so when the new elements are loaded in there then the event handlers will still work.  Also, like I said in the comments above, any script in files that you 'load()' into the page are not executed.  Glad it sorted it for you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do it like this:

```
$('#container').load("content.html", function () {
     $('#educ').click(function () {
            // any script here
     });

     $('#work').click(function () {
          // any script here
     });

     $('#skills').click(function () {
          // any script here
     });
});
```

I don't think Javascript gets executed inside a load call, so you need to put it in the callback to get it to execute.

Answer (score -1):

Bind event after DOM ready, use this code

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#educ').click(function () {
                    // any script here
                });

                $('#work').click(function () {
                    // any script here
                });

                $('#skills').click(function () {
                    // any script here
                });
    });
        </script>
```

Comment: That won't make any difference as the document is already loaded by the time the `load()` function gets this script, so it will just run immediately anyway.

Comment: This does not help at all

Answer (score -1):

$( ".resumecontent" ).load( "insert.html" );

Comment: I don't need help with the .load() script - that's easy.  I need subsequent script to run, which currently aren't work for me

Comment: okay then you can use click like that
$("#xyz").click('live',function(){ alert('check this'); });